# FROM KEYWORD NOT FOUND WHERE EXPECTED IN PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to run the following query below in Apex interactive report function body returning sql query but i get the error "FROM KEYWORD NOT FOUND WHERE EXPECTED IN PL/SQL". Kindly assist.

```
declare 
p_filter varchar2(1000);
begin 
if :P10_RATING != '0' then
p_filter := ' and RATING_ID = :P10_RATING ';
else 
-- for all we use 1=1 as filter
p_filter := ' and 1=1';
end if;
return q'~with dt as (select *
from EXCEPTIONS_LOGS where CATEGORY_ID = :P10_EXCEPTION_CATEGORY  and team_id = :P10_TEAM and USER_ID = :P10_USERID and trunc(EVENT_DATE) between :P10_START_DATE and :P10_END_DATE  ~' 
|| p_filter 
||'  order by trunc(EVENT_DATE) desc) select * cnt from dt ';
end;
```

Comment: What is the "cnt" doing in your final statement? Shouldn't it just be "select * from dt"?

Comment: I totally missed that, thought I had clear all column names i had initially listed. Thanks